# PHP : How to select specific parts of a string

Tags: php, string, substring

I was wondering... I have two strings :

```php
"CN=CMPPDepartemental_Direction,OU=1 - Groupes de sécurité,OU=CMPP_Departementale,OU=Pole_Ambulatoire,OU=Utilisateurs_ADEI,DC=doadei,DC=wan",
"CN=CMPPDepartemental_Secretariat,OU=1 - Groupes de sécurité,OU=CMPP_Departementale,OU=Pole_Ambulatoire,OU=Utilisateurs_ADEI,DC=doadei,DC=wan"
```

Is there a way in php to select only the first part of these strings ? I would like to just select **CMPPDepartemental_Direction** and **CMPPDepartemental_Secretariat**.

I had thought of trying with substr() or trim() but without success.

Comment: You have to use a regex to extract string inside `***`

Comment: @elieeee simpler / more direct regex: https://3v4l.org/iddDI

Comment: You can also modify your string to resemble a url's querystring and parse the whole string into an associative array. https://3v4l.org/0hekm  This works well on your sample input, but might not work well in other scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `preg_match` with regex `CN=(\w+_\w+)` to extract needed parts:

```php
$strs = [
    "CN=CMPPDepartemental_Direction,OU=1 - Groupes de sécurité,OU=CMPP_Departementale,OU=Pole_Ambulatoire,OU=Utilisateurs_ADEI,DC=doadei,DC=wan",
    "CN=CMPPDepartemental_Secretariat,OU=1 - Groupes de sécurité,OU=CMPP_Departementale,OU=Pole_Ambulatoire,OU=Utilisateurs_ADEI,DC=doadei,DC=wan"
];

foreach ($strs as $str) {
    $matches = null;

    preg_match('/CN=(\w+_\w+)/', $str, $matches);

    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: You do realize that underscore is included in `\w`, right?  Also, `$matches = null;` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings always have the same structure, I recommend using a custom function `find_by_keyword` - so you can search for other keywords too.

```
function find_by_keyword( $string, $keyword ) {
    $array = explode(",",$string);
    $found = [];
    // Loop through each item and check for a match.
    foreach ( $array as $string ) {
        // If found somewhere inside the string, add.
        if ( strpos( $string, $keyword ) !== false ) {
            $found[] = substr($string, strlen($keyword));
        }
    }
    return $found;
}

var_dump(find_by_keyword($str2, "CN=")); 

// array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "CMPPDepartemental_Direction"
}

var_dump(find_by_keyword($str2, "OU="));
//array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "1 - Groupes de sécurité"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "CMPP"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Pole"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "Utilisateurs"
}
```

Examle [here](https://3v4l.org/qA6MU).